# How to handle POST restful webservice in Spring MVC which consume and produce data and image both

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I am developing webservice which contain some information with image , for example , develop webservice which contain user information with photo. I want this done by POST request. How can I achieve this?

I want to store only image path in database.

What changes should i make in controller to retrive image from mobile and store it in database? I am taking UserInfoTemp object as request body.

To developing webservice I am using Spring MVC 4.0.3.Release.

Here is my code please review it:

```
@Entity
public class UserInfoTemp
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="UserId")  
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="Email")
    @JsonProperty(value="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="Phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name="ProfilePicLink")
    private String profilePicLink;
    @Column(name="ProfilePicThumbnailLink")
    private String profilePicThumbnailLink; 

//getter setter
}
```

Controller:-

```
// for registering user
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> register(@RequestBody UserInfoTemp userInfoTemp) 
    {
        try 
        {
            userInfoService.save(userInfoTemp);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(userInfoTemp, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setStatus(false);
            message.setMessage("User information can not be null");
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(message, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

    }
```

Comment: As I understand you've got the image already stored in the server?

Comment: What about your client side? how you are passing data to server?